# Extracting text between anchor tag in beautifulsoup Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the name of the movies listed on this fandango page.

```
names_tag = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'dark showtimes-movie-title'})
```

This is the anchor class the names are withheld in. The issue is, when I run the code, the output is:

```
<a class="dark showtimes-movie-title" href="http://www.fandango.com/godzilla3d_170083/movieoverview">Godzilla 3D</a>
```

When all I want in Godzilla 3D. How can I successfully parse this data?

```
#anchor element containing the names of each movie
names_tag = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'dark showtimes-movie-title'})
names_tag = str(names_tag)

movie_name = names_tag.split(',')

for each_line in movie_name:
    movie_names.append(each_line)

i = 0
while (i < len(movie_names)):

    print 'The length of %s is %s' %(movie_names[i], movie_times[i])

    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text` property:

```
names_tag = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'dark showtimes-movie-title'})
names = [name_tag.text for name_tag in names_tag]
```

Comment: It's not working in this case. I will add more code to show what it looks like.

Comment: I'm appending names to list to print out in loop iterator